# Enumerate image resources in dotnet MAUI

Tags: c#, .net-core, maui, .net-maui

I have a folder structure in my MAUI project

```
/Resources
  /Images
    dotnet_bot.svg
    
    /LocationTypeIcons
      _default.svg
      bar.svg
      restaurant.svg
      grocery.svc
      ...
```

and then in my csproj I have

```
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\LocationTypeIcons\*" />
```

I'm trying to find a way to, in code, iterate over the icons that I have in the LocatationTypeIcons folder to conditionally use one if the name of a field matches it, but use _default if it doesn't.

I'm looking to do something like

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles( "???/LocationTypeIcons" )
```

Or maybe something along the lines of

```
App.Current.Resources.GetResourcesByTypeAndPath("Images", "LocationTypeIcons");
```

really anything that works, I know that I can build the following map, but I was trying to avoid having to put the data in a bunch of places and wanted to let the presence of the svgs and their filenames dictate which icons were available.

```
   public static Dictionary<string, string> TypeMap = new {
     { "bar", "bar.png" },
     { "restaurant", "restaurant.png" },
     { "grocery", "grocery.png" }
   };
```

If I have to do something platform specific for each platform, that's fine too (though obv not preferred) but even in platform specific code, I'm not sure how to access this information.

Comment: @Jason, thanks, if only though... that only gives me the list of all the xaml files (including Colors.xaml and Styles.xaml which are in the resources folder) from my project.  None of my image or font resources are present when I do this, even if they've already been loaded and displayed on the screen.

Comment: Upon further attempts, `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()` _does_, in fact, return the image resources, but only if I change their BuildAction from `MauiImage` to `EmbeddedResource`.  Does anyone know if this will have any adverse effects on the behavior, performance, or portability of my app?

Comment: When you add images to the *Resources\Images* folder of your project, where its build action will automatically be set to `MauiImage`. At build time, vector images are resized to the correct resolutions for the target platform and device, and added to your app package. And the operating system chooses the appropriate image resolution at runtime based on the device's capabilities.  Well you want to do something about `MauiImage` by `EmbeddedResource`. It(`EmbeddedResource`) will conflict with the mechanism described preceding

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT Is there's no way to get a collection of generated images?